# ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhijithpr/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 31, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/RTD/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/RTD/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/RTD/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import object_detection_evaluation
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/RTD/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/utils/object_detection_evaluation.py", line 46, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/RTD/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (/opt/anaconda3/envs/RTD/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/protos/__init__.py)
```

I am trying to my final project please help
I am using MacBook Air for this project
If you want any other info Please Ask

Thanks!!

im trying to recreate the real time hand gesture recognition project.

Comment: send your bug reports to the author of the "object_detection" package.

Comment: Looks like you're supposed to run `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` first. Have you already done that? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1595#issuecomment-309234210